# IValueConverter with MarkupExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, ivalueconverter, markup-extensions

Recently I read about an `IValueConverter` which also inherits from `MarkupExtension`. It was something like:

```
internal class BoolToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    private static BoolToVisibilityConverter converter;
    public BoolToVisibilityConverter()
    {
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Visibility)
        {
            Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
            if (visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return converter ?? (converter = new BoolToVisibilityConverter());
    }
}
```

The usage than looks like:

```
<Button Content="Delete" Visibility="{Binding CanDelete, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={local:BoolToVisibilityConverter}"/>
```

I was used to use converters from a Resource like:

```
<loc:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
...
<Button Content="Delete" Visibility="{Binding CanDelete, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}"/>
```

My first question now is: What is the better way? What advantages does it have if I'm using the `MarkupExtension-Version` (Beside the usage is easier to type)?

I also saw a very similar implementation which looks like:

```
internal class BoolToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public BoolToVisibilityConverter()
    {
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Visibility)
        {
            Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
            if (visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;        
    }
}
```

If I understand it right, the first solution only creates one instance of this converter. The second one creates for every XAML a new instance of this converter, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only (slight) advantage that the markup extension is providing in this case is more concise XAML syntax.

Instead of this:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
...
{Binding SomeBooleanProperty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}
```

you can have this:

```
{Binding SomeBooleanProperty, Converter={my:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}
```

In my opinion it's not really worth it. If you were that bothered about saving keystrokes you could just shorten the key used to reference the converter:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="btvc" />
...
{Binding SomeBooleanProperty, Converter={StaticResource my:btvc}}
```

---

As the `ProvideValue` method of the markup extension is an *instance* method, it can only be called once an instance of the class has been created. As the class is both a markup extension and a converter, both variants of the code will create a converter each time. The only difference is that the first variant will always *return the same converter*: it won't however, stop another converter from being *created*.

Answer (score 17):

One massive advantage of using `MarkupExtension` which I have never seen being used online is the fact it can allow you pass values to the converter which could be used as argument or return values, for example:

```
public class CustomNullToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object NullValue { get; set; }
    public object NotNullValue { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return NullValue;

        return NotNullValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
...
Visibility="{Binding Property, 
            Converter={cnv:CustomNullToVisibilityConverter 
                       NotNullValue=Visible, NullValue=Collapsed}}" />
...
```

Be sure to reference the namespace of the converter in the `.xaml`.

---

Edit:

One thing I forgot to mention is that yes you are correct in the fact that this method would create a new instance of the converter each time it's used which is one downside.

However there nothing to stop you adding a converter with `MarkupExtension` to a resource dictionary - that way it will only be instanced once. Like so:

```
<cnv:CustomNullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter"
        NotNullValue=Visible, NullValue=Collapsed />
...
Visibility="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}" />
...
```

Comment: Thanks for finally giving an example of a GOOD usage of MarkupExtension.