# ValueConverter Convert Methods are not invoked in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reactive

I am having ValueConverter which I am trying to use. 
All bindings, including DataGrid content are working correctly, but I can't apply Value converter neither to the DataGridColumns, not to other fields, because it's methods are not invoked at all.

Possible problematic place could be the fact that we are using **Reactive UI** as MVVM framework, so it can be a possible source of problem. I am setting Items Source of the DataGrid via Reactive UI bindings.

But I have tried to set something like on the view:

```
 public partial class OrderTimeSheetUserControl : OrderTimeSheetBaseUserControl
    {
        public OrderTimeSheetUserControl()
        {
            this.DataContext = ViewModel; // Set data context in case it may have helped (but it did not)
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

P.S.: I have tried built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter, as well as writing my converter with inheritance of MarkupExtension class and slightly different method of usage. ([IValueConverter with MarkupExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501091/ivalueconverter-with-markupextension))

**Value Converter below:**

```
  [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BoolToCollapsedVisibilityValueConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool == false)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Conversion from {value.GetType().Name} is not supported by {nameof(BoolToCollapsedVisibilityValueConverter)}.");
        }

        var boolValue = (bool) value;

        return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

**And it's usage in the XAML page:**

```
 <userControls:OrderTimeSheetBaseUserControl.Resources>

 <wpfValueConverters:BoolToCollapsedVisibilityValueConverter x:Key="Conv" />
```

```
 <DataGrid>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridComboBoxColumn Visibility="{Binding BackPayCategoryVisible, Converter={StaticResource Conv}}" Header="Backpay Cat."/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

**Reactive UI Binding of the ItemsSource of the DataGrid in xaml.cs:**

```
   this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
                    viewModel => viewModel.Employees,
                    view => view.PersonsInOrderDataGrid.ItemsSource)
                .DisposeWith(disposable);
```

So, all properties are bound correctly, but value converters are not working.

Comment: *"Set data context in case it may have helped (but it did not)"*. So all of your bindings to viewmodel properties are working, regardless of whether or not you have a viewmodel at all? Please [provide a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If `BackPayCategoryVisible` is a property of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`'s DataContext (I have no way of knowing if that's the case), and if the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`'s DataContext raises `PropertyChanged` with `"BackPayCategoryVisible"` for a property name when it should, your code will work.

Comment: "for *the correct* property name when it should" -- but I have no way of knowing whether that happens either. The problem certainly isn't in any code you've shown us. Built-in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` would work fine as well.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I am using ReactiveUi binding for all the view, but for the DataGridColumns their data context is ItemsSource item, and for the binding of the columns I had to use WPF bindings. I will add more code to question.

Comment: I can’t reproduce the issue from that. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: At runtime, look in the Output pane in Visual Studio for binding errors. You can add PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High to a broken binding and it'll give you a lot more detail in the Output pane about exactly how and where it runs into trouble resolving the source property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataGridColumn` doesn't inherit any `DataContext` by default, so your binding fails and that's why the converter is never invoked. This has nothing to do with ReactiveUI.

You can get the binding to work by using a `Freezable` as suggested in this [blog](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) post:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
...
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Backpay Cat." Binding="{Binding Price}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Data.BackPayCategoryVisible,
                        Converter={StaticResource Conv},
                        Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
```